# Perl OR conditions

Tags: perl, conditional-statements

i have a code with many OR conditions like this (working fine) to check if one of the values is empty, then we throw an error message (all of them must be filled)

```
 } elsif (
    !$params{'account'} 
    || !$params{'type'} 
    || !$params{'sampledate'} 
    || !$params{'lastpwchange'} 
    || !$params{'system'} 
    || !$params{'wspass'}
) {
    print $cgi->header("text/plain"), "some mandatory parameters are missing";
}
```

i need to add many other variables in that condition, making the line a bit unreadable.

i was wondering if there was a more elegant way of specifying all of them, maybe using an array/list of some kind ?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [handy module `List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util), you can do something like:

```
use List::Util qw/any/;

...
elsif (any { !$params{$_} } qw/account type sampledate lastpwchange system wspass/) {
    print $cgi->header("text/plain"), "some mandatory parameters are missing";
}
```

Please note that your expression does not *exactly* checks for emptiness; it actually performs a boolean check, so a parameter having value `0` would also fail the check. This might, or might not be what you want.

Comment: This may not apply to the OP's question, but in general `any` is faster than `grep`. From the docs: *Many cases of using "grep" in a conditional can be written using "any" instead, as **it can short-circuit after the first true result**.*

Comment: @Timur Sharland, `grep` is [more than twice as fast](https://pastebin.com/6g6QgGg2) in the case here most favorable to `any` here. The reason is that the `any` version requires two subroutine calls, while the `grep` version requires none. Both the call to `any` and the condition "block" passed to `any` are subroutine calls, and those are expensive. `grep` is an operator (not a subroutine), and the block passed to `grep` is truly a block (not a subroutine).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`grep`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to do that.

```
my %stuff = map { $_ => 1 } qw/ foo bar baz qrr qux asdf hello world /;
$stuff{foo} = 1; # toggle here

my $missing = grep { ! $stuff{$_} } qw/ foo bar baz qrr qux asdf hello world /;
print "missing argument" if $missing;
```

Comment: `grep` is the best solution if you either do not want to use any modules, or if you want to keep **all** keys selected by the condition (e.g., to print as part of the error message), e.g, `my @missing = grep ... ; print "missing arguments: @missing" if @missing;`